# Multiple UPDATES and INSERTS from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a assigning a string with semicolon-separated `INSERT` and `UPDATES` to `SqlCommmand.CommandText`, then calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

It "works" but I'm worried about what will happen when there are 40,000 INSERTS in the string.  Does all this happen in a single SQL Transaction? Should I batch them somehow, and how big should the batches be?

Comment: are the 40,000 insert for the same table?

Comment: 40.000 isn't too much I think.

Comment: It is one-time insert or it is standard state of your DB?

Comment: Multiple statements are never in a single transaction unless you explicitly put them into a transaction yourself.

Comment: Each of these would be working on a separate table.  It would happen daily, kind of a small scale data warehouse arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 40.000 inserts, you probably *want* them to happen in a single transaction: it's good for performance and even better for error recovery (you won't get partially filled table if something goes wrong). And as far as I know, it doesn't happen automatically (i.e. there is no transaction if you don't start one and if there's no implicitly *opening* transactions on the database level (which would require explicit commit anyway)).

I would recommend to use prepared query with parameters, running it in a loop, all within an explicitly opened transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have strong schema of inserted values, consider usage of [user-defined table type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
You can pass `DataTable` as parameter into command (custom command or stored-procedure).

It's much more straight-forward than CSV.

And I agree with @Anton Kovalenko - if you insert large amount of rows, you should do it at once. Only if you want insert extra-large (for example milions) amount or rows, split it into several batched but don't insert every row separately.

Answer (score 0):

For 40.000 inserts you want them in SEPARATE Transactions that are handleed in multiple threads. Or you want them to happen using SqlBUlkCopy to a temp table, not via string inserts.

Basically, create a temporary table, sqlbulkcopy into the temporary table, copy over with an insert into select from.

This is a LOT faster than all the SQL text parsing. Batches - well, I regularly do Batches Close to 100.000 rows in inserts. Performance is around 75k rows per second like this.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on the total number ob bytes you try to send in one command.
The only limit I know is the batch size which would be 65,536 * Network Packet Size (usually 4096) = 268 435 456 bytes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Thanks, no way we'll hit that

Comment: Sorry, what Network are you using? Ethernet has either 1500 payload size or für Jumbo Frames (that VERY few People use) 9000 as per standardization. NOTHING I k now uses 4096 Byte Network packets.

Comment: for 4096 packet size have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187866(v=sql.105).aspx

btw, dont know why my answer was down voted...